# Spring 3 with Hibernate 4--unit test failure with No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have used Spring and Hibernate for years, but this is my first project using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4.

I set up the Model class such:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DICTIONARY_ENTRY", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "DICTIONARY_UUID", "ANAGRAM", "WORD" }))
public class DictionaryEntry extends Pojo implements
        Comparable<DictionaryEntry> {
    @Column(name = "ANAGRAM", nullable = false)
    private String anagram;

    @Column(name = "WORD", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String word;

    @Column(name = "DEFINITION", nullable = false)
    private String definition;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DICTIONARY_UUID", referencedColumnName = "UUID", nullable=false)
    private Dictionary dictionary;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fromEntry")
    /*package*/ Set<CrossReference> fromReferences;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "toEntry")
    /*package*/ Set<CrossReference> toReferences;
```

Per the directions in the Spring manual, I then set up my DAO and inject in an instance of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean. Then I call getSession() which is:

```
  /**
   * Get the current session for a hibernate query
   * @return the current session
   */
  protected Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  }
```

I then run my unit test, inject in my session factory and run this method:

```
object = (T) getSession().save(object);
```

Which throws:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:980)
    at com.heavyweight.lexaholic.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.getSession(HibernateDAO.java:86)
    at com.heavyweight.lexaholic.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.create(HibernateDAO.java:59)
    at com.heavyweight.lexaholic.dao.hibernate.lexicon.DictionaryEntryHibernateDAOTest.testCRD(DictionaryEntryHibernateDAOTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:980)
    at com.heavyweight.lexaholic.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.getSession(HibernateDAO.java:86)
    at com.heavyweight.lexaholic.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.commit(HibernateDAO.java:41)
    at com.heavyweight.lexaholic.dao.hibernate.lexicon.DictionaryEntryHibernateDAOTest.tearDown(DictionaryEntryHibernateDAOTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here's the Spring configuration:

```
  <bean id="testDatabase" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>org.h2.Driver</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</value></property>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="testDatabase"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="testSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="testDatabase" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
        <value>com.heavyweight.lexaholic.model.lexicon.CrossReference</value>
        <value>com.heavyweight.lexaholic.model.lexicon.Dictionary</value>
        <value>com.heavyweight.lexaholic.model.lexicon.DictionaryEntry</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        hibernate.show_sql=false
        hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
        hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
    </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="dictionaryEntryDAO" class="com.heavyweight.lexaholic.dao.hibernate.lexicon.DictionaryEntryHibernateDAO" init-method="init">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="testSessionFactory" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: Spring configuration?

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you need to modify:

Firstly, you are using Hibernate for persistence, so you need to use HibernateTransactionManager instead of DataSourceTransactionManager.

```
<!-- Transaction Configuration For All Services (including Hibernate and MyBatis)-->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction: enable annotation-driven transaction -->
<!--Put @Transactional on service impl instead of service interface-->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Secondly, you are using Hibernate 4.x, so you need to configure ***current session context class*** like this:

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
```

For information, reference http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/

I hope you pass it

Comment: just to add on, you will not be able to get the session if you want to use spring transactions, refer to this link for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832889/spring-transactions-and-hibernate-current-session-context-class

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my junit test in a spring 3 application with hibernate 3.6.
When the application runs on application server, the sessions is managed with session filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

But when run junit it is not loaded, you have to simulate it in your test.
One solution as suggested is to use @TransactionConfiguration or extending AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests but it not works if you have a Service Layer classes annotated with @Service @Transactional and you call it several times in your test.

I solved as following, according to [this](http://bansihaudakari.wordpress.com/spring/integration-testing-with-junit-and-spring/) post:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:context.xml"})
public class JUnitTestBase extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    protected Log logger;

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected FlushMode flushMode = FlushMode.MANUAL;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Session session = getSession(this.sessionFactory);
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory,new SessionHolder(session));
        logger.debug("Hibernate session is bound");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        SessionHolder sessionHolder = (SessionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sessionFactory);
        closeSession(sessionHolder.getSession(), sessionFactory);
        logger.debug("Hibernate session is closed");
    }

    protected void closeSession(Session session, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(session);
    }

    protected Session getSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory) throws DataAccessResourceFailureException {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true);
        FlushMode flushMode = this.flushMode;
        if (flushMode != null) {
            session.setFlushMode(flushMode);
        }
        return session;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your test may be missing TransactionConfiguration annotation. Try the following -

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager")
```

Alternatively, you could change your bean definition for transaction manager as follows -

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="testDatabase"/>
```

By default spring tries to find 'transactionManager' bean.

Comment: I renamed txManager to transactionManager but no joy. Haven't been able to find the jar file with @TransactionConfiguration yet.

Comment: Could you post your test class ?