# org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction in my case

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have `GenericService` class which encapsulates crud methods for subclasses:

```
public abstract class GenericService<D extends GenericDao<T, I>, T extends DomainObject<I>, I> {

    public I save(T t) {
        return getDao().save(t);
    }
...........................
}
```

Class `AnswerService` extends `GenericService`. It autowires `AnswerDao` and declares itself as `@Service` and `@Transactional` spring component.

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class AnswerService extends GenericService<AnswerDao, Answer, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private AnswerDao answerDao;

    @Override
    public void setDao(AnswerDao d) {
        this.answerDao = d;
    }

    @Override
    public AnswerDao getDao() {
        return answerDao;
    }
................................
}
```

`AnswerDao` extends `GenericDao` which implements method `save`.

```
public abstract class GenericDaoHibernate<T extends DomainObject<I>, I extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, I> {

    private Class<? extends T> entityClass;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public GenericDaoHibernate(Class<? extends T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public GenericDaoHibernate() {
    }

    @Autowired
    private void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        Assertor.assertNotNull(sessionFactory);
    }

    public Session currentSession() {
        return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public I save(T entity) {
        // Transaction transaction = currentSession().beginTransaction();
        I id = (I) currentSession().save(entity);
        // transaction.commit();
        return id;
    }
```

When I call `save` method on `GenericService` I expect spring to create transaction for hibernate Session, but transaction is not created and I get this error right in `GenericDaoHibernate.save` method:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
```

My spring config file for service layer is:

```
<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory -->
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.javahelp.domain.impl">
            <property name="configLocations">
                <array>
                    <value>classpath:META-INF/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
                </array>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <!-- A transaction manager for working with Hibernate session methods. 
            Without this transaction manager none method of hibernate session works -->
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

    <!-- enable scanning for @Transactional annotation -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <!-- autodetect all spring @Service beans in package com.javahelp.service 
            (service layer) -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.javahelp.service" />
```

So when I don't rely on spring @Transactional support and begin/commit transaction by `org.hibernate.Session` then all is ok and I have no error.

Why spring doesn't provide transaction for methods called on GenericSerice?

BTW, GenericService and AnswerService have no interfaces.

**EDIT**. This is transaction that is returned by `HibernateTransactionManager.doGetTransaction` method:

```
txObject    HibernateTransactionManager$HibernateTransactionObject  (id=190)    
    connectionHolder    null    
    newSession  false   
    newSessionHolder    false   
    previousIsolationLevel  null    
    savepointAllowed    false   
    sessionHolder   null
```

I also changed my services to use interfaces but it didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

Don't know the root cause, but removing the below property from my hibernate configuration solved the problem for me.

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
```

Found on this [forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/428921/ORM/databases/Spring-Hibernate-Jboss-JTA-getCurrentSession)

Comment: worth looking at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832889/spring-transactions-and-hibernate-current-session-context-class as it is explained in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`getCurrentSession()`  : Obtains the current session.

Creates a new session, different from the contextual session

`openSession()` : Returns: The created session.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, but this fixed my problem! Makes sense too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I´, using org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager for my TransactionManager and Hibernate adapter in my entitymanager.

```
       <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="domain"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value-ref="mySQLMultiTenantConnectionProvider" />
            <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="tenantIdentifierResolver" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I suggest to changes to this configuration.

But if you dont, try to debug in HibernateTransactionManager in the method doGetTransaction  ans see what´s going on.

Comment: Please,see my edits. Indeed that method returns empty `HibernateTransactionObject`.

Comment: Actually placing values directly in `hibernate.cfg.xml` didn't help too. I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell about which methods or classes that needs transnational support from Spring .
@Transnational Annotation (can be specified on method or class level) guarantees transnational behavior for the annotated methods and classes but not to the entire application.

Answer (score -1):

Add @Transactional annotations to your dao methods as well.