# spring mvc + hibernate: createSQLQuery is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

The old version of my code:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("From User");
    List<Users> users = query.list();
    session.close();
```

I config the hibernate.cfg.xml file：

> <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" >  thread</property >

context.xml

> <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

Current code:

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  Query query = session.createQuery("From User");
  List<Users> list = query.list();
  tx.commit();
```

I have to add Transaction code, or I will get an error

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction

What am I missing for the config?

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  ......
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
</bean>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="*" />      
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager"       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>


public class IndexController {


@Autowired
UserService users;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index(ModelMap model ) {

 User user=   users.test();
 model.put("user", user);
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Please, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832889/spring-transactions-and-hibernate-current-session-context-class. It may helps you.

Comment: @eg04lt3r The post recommends to remove current_session_context_class. if I remove it, it will be a no session error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested @eg04lt3r you don't need this line in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

You need to configure your spring context properly.

For the session factory, if you have mapping and properties in `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `hibernate.properties`

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"  
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" />
```

for a transaction management

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"   
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

In a class that works with a session

```
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public List<User> list() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
        return (List<User>) query.list();
    }

}
```

You can't get users by this way of course

```
new Service().list()
```

You need to get `Service` from the spring context. Spring will set  `sessionFactory` in the `Service` and return a proxy for `Service`. When you call `list()` a proxy open a session and create a transaction.

**Update**

I reproduce your problem. With this classes everything works fine

```
public interface TextService {

    public void save();

    public List<SingleText> test();

}


@Service
public class TextServiceImpl implements TextService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save() {
        SingleText text = new SingleText();
        text.setTestText("S.Grey");

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(text);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<SingleText> test() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.createCriteria(SingleText.class).list();
    }

}
```

Without the `@Transactional` annotation I got

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`

or (it depends of the Spring version)

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`

So you just need the `@Transaction` annotation. And you don't need this

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: You must be sure that you get UserService from the spring context?  I don't understand this.

Comment: @JohnZhang Spring must set this `@Autowired UserService users;` not you by `UserService users = new UserService();`

Comment: @JohnZhang You can put your project on github or bitbucket and add the link to your question. I think it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this property if you do not use JTA. Spring do management transaction by default.

And define transaction manager in spring configuration:

```
<bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: if I remove it, it will be a no session error, When I use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Comment: Yes, spring will return current session.

Comment: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread