# Hibernate4, Spring4.3, Thread, Session

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, session

i have the following declared in spring.xml:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  ...
  </bean>
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
  </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Adapters -->
    <bean id="ADBAdapter" class="model.adapter.ADBAdapter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

So after i created the context. I can Access my ADBAdapter and do stuff.

The Problem is, that i want to use ADBAdapter in another Thread.
But then i get sometimes a SessionClosed Exception, because the session gets closed in the parent thread.

How can I handle this ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Finally the problem was, that i passed Hibernate Entities through Thread bounds.
I solved the problem, by passing only the Oid(primary key) and load it again in the Thread itself.

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate you can use

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

Comment: In this Thread they say its not recommend like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832889/spring-transactions-and-hibernate-current-session-context-class